# Using multiple JS files in an Electron project

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am making a basic Electron app but I'm stuck on how to use multiple JavaScript files in my project. I have `window.js` to render my window, but I want to have `scripts.js` to do everything else. I could use a `<script>` tag, but I want to have Node functions in it, so that wouldn't work. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can have Node functions in the renderer process! You'll need to make sure `nodeIntegration` is enabled when setting up the BrowserWindow:

```
let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    },
    center: true
})
```

Check the [BrowserWindow](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) documentation for further info.

Answer (score 0):

Node js is for server side using. Its syntactic  might use on front too  but with using additional libraries or package builders like web pack  or angular minifier.
There is example with using Node.js and electron:
https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app

Could you provides details about your goals?